# Filter data using group by

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have this data
[image]

I want to filter this table to get another table contain quantity of each item which driver have.
I tried to use group by driver_id but it count all items with the driver. I don't need that I need quantity of each item with the driver.
I need a result table like this
[image]

Comment: Hint: Use `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY` item_id and then by driver_id 
and `COUNT` function to count the number of records for each group.

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT item_id,COUNT(*) AS quantity,driver_id FROM `table`
GROUP BY item_id,driver_id
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to group by both the item_id and the driver_id:

```
group by driver_id, item_id
```

Comment: This is an incomplete answer.